# Angular how to turn the decimal to (.)

Tags: angular

how do i turn some of the decimal to period(.) or dot?

this is my html

```
<p class="pointer" >{{grade.odds ? redot(grade.odds) : '--'}} </p>
```

this is my .ts

```
 redot(n){
    n = n.replace('%', '');
    console.log('n', n)
    n = this.env.moneyFormat(n, 2);
    return n + '%';
  }
```

for example

student 1 grade result : 100.452343234 %

what i desired result

student 1 grade result : 100.45....... %

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a useful pipe called [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) that solves the problem, so, no need of creating a new function.

Just use:

```
<p class="pointer" >{{grade.odds | number:'3.1-2'}} </p>
```

or if you want it to always have 2 digits after dot, then use:

```
<p class="pointer" >{{grade.odds | number:'3.2-2'}} </p>
```

P.S.: The format `'3.1-2'` means the number will have 3 digits before the dots, and 1-2 digits after the dot.